Summertime by DJ Jazzy Jeff and The Fresh Prince background vocals
In the chorus of the song "Summertime", in the background, behind the main vocals there is a repeating lyric that is not listed ANYWHERE on the internet. I've been trying to figure this out for years! It's not part of either of the samples used in the song.
Sounds to me like they are saying "that's enough"...or maybe "pack it up"? Any insight is appreciated.
For reference, check out 0:14–0:19 of the song. Sounds like "summer time, that's enough....summer time, that's enough…"
The song also ends with this chant isolated.

oh thank god someone else has acknowledged this. https://www.reddit.com/r/lyrichelp/comments/1fw19bs/summertime_dj_jazzy_jeff_and_the_fresh_prince/   Please update your question to mention the original artist so that this gets better traction in search results.

I think the chances of finding a definitive answer from a primary source are very slim.  The song is about enjoying the summer, so I'm pretty sure it's "got ta LOVE summertime."

The refrain is "Summertime (rest) Somethin Somethin" with full long pause in between. So your idea only works if it's "Summertime, got to love!"
